How can I convert a discrete coordinate map into a data flow diagram in python?
I have some data stored in a database with the following schema
table1, field1, table2, field2

This shows how table 1 relates to table 2 via the field value. I'd like to turn this into a diagram that shows how each of these tables are related to each (i.e. an ER diagram). For example, using the above record, you would have two boxes, one labeled table1, the other labeled table2, and they are connected via two lines labeled field1 and field2. Is there any python package that can accomplish this?
Thanks

Welcome to [so]. Please read How To Ask a Good Question. "please help me" is not a question; we don't write code to specification. You are expected to study the problem ahead of time; think of logical steps to solve the problem; figure out exactly where you are stuck, and be able to show exact input and output.

I'm not asking for code, I'm asking if anyone knows of a python package that will support that function.

Providing a library or software package recommendation results in opinion based responses, which are not the purpose of this site. Try Software Recommendations for this type of question.
